# Dynamic element width and IE9 subpixel precision

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 3 divs, #left, #center and #right that I want to position on the same line which has a specific width, say 300px.

#left and #right have little content, say 50px each, and I am displaying them fully.

#center has a lot of content, say 400px, and I want to display as much as possible within the remaining space on the line. For this, I have included the content of #center within #inner.

I have floated #left and #center to left and #right to right.

```
<div id="left">
    LEFT
</div>
<div id="center">
    <div id="inner">
        LONG CONTENT ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    RIGHT
</div>
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7nJU/4/)

Question 1: Is there a way of making the #center div take all of the available remaining space on the line through CSS (in our example, #center has to be 200px wide - the width of the line, 300px, minus the width of #left and #right, each 50px) ?

Question 2: I did not find a solution through CSS and I have used jQuery to dynamically calculate the remaining available space. This works ok in all browsers except IE9.

The problem with IE9 is that it has subpixel precision and jQuery returns only integer values for the dimensions of elements.

Here's an example: IE9 sees #left as having 50.5px width while jQuery sees it as having 50px. This difference causes the layout to break in IE9.

If I need to calculate the available space through JavaScript, what can I do to overcome this IE9 issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but could you just floor the value returned and make 50.5 go to 50? If the values are always more, then this will work. If it was say 49.5, then you will be a pixel short, but this atleast won't cause your content to not fit.

Comment: There is no way for me to affect the float value used the IE9 in it's layout. When I call the element width with jQuery in IE9, it always returns an integer, 50px. But in in't internal display, IE9 uses floats, 50.5px. I know this because I looked over the IE9 developer tools and for the element dimensions it displays float values.

Comment: So when you set the width to 50px, ie9 sets it to 50.5px? That is strange... I've lined things up like this before on a pixel level and never had trouble. Seems strange.  Well good luck, sorry I wasn't able to help!

Comment: No, you said "floor the value returned", but jquery never returns a float value, it only returns integer values, even when internally, IE9 shows the width as a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, what I did was to force the width that IE9 sees as a float to the value that jQuery sees as an integer:

```
var elem = $("#element");
elem.css("width", elem.width());
```

If #element had a value seen by IE9 as 50.5px, jQuery forces a value upon it that jQuery sees, 50px.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
main = $("#main").width();
centerWidth = main - ( $("#left").width() + $("#right").width() );
$("#center").width(centerWidth);
```

or:

```
main = parseFloat(document.getElementById("main").style.width)
centerWidth = main - (parseFloat(document.getElementById("left").style.width) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("right").style.width));
document.getElementById("center").style.width = centerWidth + "px"
```

Comment: I specified that I did this and it does not work in IE9 because IE9 has float values for width and jquery only returns integer values. Example: IE9 sees #left as 50.5px, jquery sees #left as 50px. This float value will cause the layout to break because it cannot fit in the calculated value because of the 0.5px more that IE9 sees.

Comment: There is nothing to use the Math.ceil() on because jquery always returns the element width as an integer. Only IE9, internally sees it as a float.

Comment: The only way that I have found to overcome this is to force the width that jquery sees on the element seen as a float. Example: $("#left").css("left", $("#left").width()); If IE9 will see #left as 50.5px, jquery will force a width of 50px. But this method does not seem ideal.

Comment: try `.innerWidth()`, yes, `width()` returns an integer value for  calculating better.

Comment: Based on my tests and the jQuery API (http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/), innerWidth also returns an integer.

Comment: so why not using `document.getElementById("left").style.width` property?

Comment: Doesn't the "style.width" return the width specified in the CSS ? Because I have the element content dynamic, I don't have a set width for it.

Comment: yes, it returns css width, i think it's better to force ie to set the width as an integer, like 51px or 50px.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only thing that I found to work so far but like I mentioned a little earlier, it does not seem as ideal, but then again, IE problems don't have ideal solutions, do they ?!

Comment: you are right, no, users that use ie as main browser are condemned to see the page strangely, ie6, 7, 8, 9, 10 5 browsers with 5 different behaviors idk why people use this non-standard browser.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
el = $('#myelement');

//Hello IE9-10 and float "width", e.g. 83.41px;
try {
  var elWidth = Math.ceil(parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el[0]).width)); 
} 
//But old browser doesn't know "getComputedStyle()" e.g. IE 8 and oldest;
catch (e) {
  var elWidth = el.width(); 
}

elWidth; //IE 9-10 return 84px, other browsers 83px;
```